# discord.py rank system leaderboard

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am currently trying to make a leaderboard for my Discord.py level system so that you do !Leaderboard and then an embed comes with place 1, 2, 3 and so on

The Level and Exp is stored in a Json looks like that:

```
{"589898942527963157": {"experience": 25, "level": 2, "LastMessage": 202108011409}, "538477109148909599": {"experience": 0, "level": 0, "LastMessage": 202107312203}}
```

Does anyone have ideas how I can get it sorted according to the highest level and then make it into a leaderboard with place 1 2 3 etc.

And my Code at the Moment looks like that:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
from datetime import datetime
import os
import random

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Anwender\PycharmProjects\Normalo-Bot')


class levels(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await self.update_data(users, member)

        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
      if not message.author.bot:
        with open('users.json','r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await self.update_data(users, message.author)
        if(users[str(message.author.id)]['LastMessage'] < await self.to_integer(datetime.now())):
            await self.add_experience(users, message.author)
        await self.level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)


        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    async def update_data(self, users, user):
        if not str(user.id) in users:
            users[str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(user.id)]['level'] = 0
            users[str(user.id)]['LastMessage'] = await self.to_integer(datetime.now())

    async def add_experience(self, users, user):
        users[str(user.id)]['experience'] += random.randint(15,25)
        users[str(user.id)]['LastMessage'] = await self.to_integer(datetime.now())


    async def level_up(self, users, user,message):
        experience = users[str(user.id)]['experience']
        lvl = users[str(user.id)]['level']
        lvl_end = 5 * (lvl ** 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100
        print(user)
        print(f"Level:{lvl}")
        print(f"experience:{experience}")
        print(f"lvl_end: {lvl_end} ")



        if lvl_end <= experience:
            channel=self.client.get_channel(810855960133894154)
            await channel.send('{} has leveld up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl+1))
            users[str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl+1
            users[str(user.id)]['experience'] -= lvl_end



    async def to_integer(self, dt_time):
        answer = 100000000 * dt_time.year + 1000000 * dt_time.month + 10000 * dt_time.day + 100 * dt_time.hour + dt_time.minute
        return int(answer)

    @commands.command()
    async def rank(self,ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
        with open('users.json','r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        if user is None:
            if not str(ctx.author.id) in users:
                users[str(ctx.author.id)] = {}
                users[str(ctx.author.id)]['experience'] = 0
                users[str(ctx.author.id)]['level'] = 0
                users[str(ctx.author.id)]['LastMessage'] = await self.to_integer(datetime.now())
            user=ctx.author
            lvl = int(users[str(ctx.author.id)]['level'])
            exp = int(5 * (lvl ** 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100)
            embed = discord.Embed(Title=f"**{user}'s Rang**",Description=f"Experience: {lvl}/{5 * (lvl ** 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100}", color=0x0091ff)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{user.avatar_url}")
            embed.add_field(name=f"**{user}'s Rang**", value="  ", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Level", value=f"**{users[str(user.id)]['level']}**", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Experience", value=f"**{str(int(users[str(user.id)]['experience']))} / {exp}**",inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="Type more to level up!\nSpam is useless")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)


        else:
            if not str(user.id) in users:
                users[str(user.id)] = {}
                users[str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
                users[str(user.id)]['level'] = 0
                users[str(user.id)]['LastMessage'] = await self.to_integer(datetime.now())
            lvl = int(users[str(user.id)]['level'])
            exp=int(5 * (lvl ** 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100)
            embed=discord.Embed(Title=f"**{user}'s Rang**",Description=f"Experience: {lvl}/{5 * (lvl ** 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100}",color=0x0091ff)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{user.avatar_url}")
            embed.add_field(name=f"**{user}'s Rang**", value="  ", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Level",value=f"**{users[str(user.id)]['level']}**",inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Experience", value=f"**{str(int(users[str(user.id)]['experience']))} / {exp}**", inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="Type more to level up!\nSpam is useless")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def add_exp(self, ctx, user: discord.Member,nummer:int):
        with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        if not ctx.author.bot:
            users[str(user.id)]['experience']+=int(nummer)
            await ctx.send("exp added")
        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    @commands.command()
    async def add_lvl(self, ctx, user: discord.Member,nummer:int):
        with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        if not ctx.author.bot:
            users[str(user.id)]['level'] += int(nummer)
            await ctx.send("level added")
        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    @commands.command()
    async def add_database(self,ctx, user: discord.Member):
        with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        if not str(user.id) in users:
            users[str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(user.id)]['level'] = 0
            users[str(user.id)]['LastMessage'] = await self.to_integer(datetime.now())
            await ctx.send("added to database!")
        else:
            await ctx.send("already in database!")

        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(levels(client))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick one-liner, `sorted(x.items(), key=lambda n: n[1]['level'], reverse=True)` would be it, this will return a list with tuples, sorted from highest to lowest by the 'level' of the dict values, calling dict() on it will give you the sorted dictionary

Sort of an explanation of the code, dict.items() will return an iterable which is basically in the form of `[(key1, value1), (key2, value2)]`, and each element of the list is being passed into the lambda function, which takes the 2nd element, the value of the outer dict, and it sorts by the 'level' key of it

Comment: sounds great but i have no idea how to implement that can you send me a part of the code like where do i have to put the `sorted(x.items(), key=lambda n: n[1]['level'], reverse=True)`  im not good in coding

Comment: Well that's kind of up to you to figure out, you know you want the code to function, not me, and since we're here, if you're gonna be dynamically adding stuff it might make more sense to just use the leftover list of tuples instead of turning it to a dict since it could make adding items faster but that's minor improvements which I doubt would affect your code that much anyways